# SQL Query – records within the SQL Select statement, but NOT in the table being queried

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a large list of CustIDs that I need to query on to find if they are within the CUSTOMER table; I want the result to tell me which CustIDs ARE on the table and which CustIDs are NOT on the table.

I provided a short list below to give an idea of what I need to do.
Oracle database
Table: Customer
Primary Key:  CustID

Scenario:
Customer table only has the following (2) CustID: ‘12345’, ‘56789’

Sql:

```
Select * from CUSTOMERS where CUSTID in (‘12345’, ‘56789’, ‘01234’);
```

I want the result to tell me that both ‘12345’ and ‘56789’ are in the table, AND that ‘01234’ is NOT.

Comment: What database are you using? "SQL" by itself does not tell us enough about the needed syntax

Comment: Hi, I'm using Oracle database

Comment: Thanks. In future please use "tags" under your question (I just added Oracle) this helps those providing answers.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the "large list"? is it in a table? a file? what type of file? does it have duplicates? (or could it have duplicates?)

Comment: Hi, thanks from r the note of using the tags.

Comment: Large list - I have 1000 unique IDs, will copy from an Excel workbook and paste into  sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    v.CustID,
    exists (select * from Customer where Customer.CustID = v.CustID)
from (values (12345), (56789), (01234)) v (CustID);
```

Results:

```
custid    exists
12345     true
56789     true
1234      false
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a `left join` or subquery for this.  The precise syntax varies by database.  Typical syntax is:

```
select i.custid,
       (case when c.custid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as exists_flag
from (select '12345' as custid union all
      select '56789' union all
      select '01234'
     ) ci left join
     customers c 
     on c.cust = i.custid;
```